# Did Natasha know about Sharon/Kate's real identity when she was encouraging Steve to "call that nurse"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

Inspired by a gifset on Tumblr.

[image: Black Widow telling Captain America "what about the nurse who lives across the hall from you? Shee seems kinda nice"]

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, Natasha keeps trying to set Steve up with various women, including Kate, his neighbor who's a nurse. Later in that same movie, Steve (and us the viewers) learn that Kate is really Sharon Carter and an undercover S.H.I.E.L.D. agent.

We don't see any direct interaction between Natasha and Sharon in *CA:WS*, but they are in the same room in *Captain America: Civil War* (the gif below). However, they never speak to each other in any of the films.

[image: close up on Black Widow's head]

Do we know when Natasha learns about Sharon/Kate? Did she already know about Sharon's undercover mission and was trying to obliquely tip off Steve?

Comment: @BCdotWEB taken under advisement and removed. Thanks!

Comment: Nat didn't even know who Peggy carter was when she saw her picture in zola's bunker. Which is odd since she co-founded shield.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need something in any of the movies that says yes or no - I doubt you'll find it - but Natasha Romanov in the Marvel Universe is portrayed as the ultimate spy and an incredible double agent - I find it hard to believe she didn't know ever active SHIELD agent (and I bet she knew who Peggy Carter was and just didn't reveal it for her own reasons as she's a rather private person).

There's no certainty - but my guess is that Natasha knew everyone assigned to keep an ey on Cap because among other things, she was supposed to be helping Cap assimilate to the present (hence pushing him to date people)